# Favorite Documentation Generator system?

Tags: documentation, documentation-generation

I'm a jack-of-all-trades-master-of-none programmer and as I jump around languages, quality consistent documentation is becoming more and more important to me. I've recently been using [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/), but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_documentation_generators) reveals the usual ridiculous list of similar frameworks.

What is your favorite documentation generator and why? (Vote where you agree to keep it tidy!)

Answer (score 2):

I use different files written in MediaWiki MarkUp, since this is easy to learn for everyone. I convert this to HTML and a CHM file, and to LaTeX for the PDF documentation.

This was the most painless way for me to generate Online documentation AND printable documentation in one strike with a simple way of input.

The tools I use are org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext with a custom DocumentBuilder for LaTeX, the Microsoft Help compiler (which sadly only runs on windows), and a LaTeX distribution.

EDIT: I managed to get the Microsoft Help compiler running with Wine, so my Linux build server is now able to create the whole documentation automatically.